# How do I add an emoji on my printing text using C language?

Tags: c, text, printf, addition, emoji

```
int main()
{

   // istead of :) i want to have an emoji added to my text.

  printf("Thank you for looking into my question :) ");

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please check this emoji code : https://unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html.
You can print using emoji code. printf("%s", "\U0001f600")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You [look up](https://unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html) the unicode code for the emoji of interest, prefix the code with the universal character name `\U` when printing:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("%s", "\U0001f600"); // :-)
    return 0;
}
```

Your terminal must support unicode and the font you use must have a glyph defined for the emoji.

Comment: thanx for the share. it does not seem to be working . I am using codeblock IDE all I get is sequence of symbols when printing. as of using it on an online IDE it definitly working perfectly

Comment: Sorry, I don't know anything about the codeblock IDE.  It sounds like it doesn't have unicode output enabled (or support it?!).   File another question if you cannot find anything in the documentation.  You might also want to tag it with your OS.  The above worked with urxvt and the terminus font on Linux.